# jQuery select box replacement

Tags: jquery, select, selection

Im looking for a recommendation for jQuery select box replacement. Ive previously used the one over at BrainFault ( http://www.brainfault.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-selectbox-replacement/ ).

However, from using it and a little research into it, it is pretty bug ridden and would not recommended using it myself.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this : <strike>http://theuiguy.blogspot.com/2008/09/select-box-factory-20-for-jquery.html</strike>
edit the demo page : http://www.headcircus.com/uiguy/selectboxfactory/selectboxfactory.html (let it load)

Update: http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/ this seems to be a better option

Comment: this link requires people to be logged in. should be deleted.

Answer (score 17):

**SelectBoxIt** is a jQuery plugin that I just released that acts as an HTML select box replacment.  It is themeable with either Twitter Bootstrap or jQueryUI and is jam packed with features.

http://www.selectboxit.com

Answer (score 3):

Since jQuery UI 1.8 there has been an [autocomplete control that has a combobox functionality](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) which replaces a select control.

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery Selectbox plugin](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/) is a custom select box replacement inspired by jQuery UI source. You'll need jQuery 1.4.x or higher.

Version (0.1.3) added support for:

- optgroup
- 'disabled' attribute on both 'option' and 'optgroup'
- custom speed

It's [hosted on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/select-box/).

Answer (score 0):

[Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) Select2 is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes. It supports searching, remote data sets, and infinite scrolling of results.