# How to bold the first option of a select across all browsers?

Tags: html, css, html-select

I have tried to bold the first option of the select box but it's only working in Firefox, not other browsers (Chrome, IE). Here is the code I've tried.

HTML

```
<select id="htmldisabled">
    <option class="bold">test1</option>
    <option>test2</option>
    <option>test3</option>
    <option>test4</option>
    <option>test5</option>
    <option>test6</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
.bold {
     font-weight:bold;   
}
```

See demo at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/eqcvz/2/).

Comment: I 'm not sure if this is supported at all...

Comment: nice question mr.t.k... intresting nanba...

Answer (score 2):

```
#htmldisabled:first-child{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: not working in firefox and ie. In firefox all option are bold.

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, it can't be done cross-browser ;)

Best to use a [selectbox replacement script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021836/jquery-select-box-replacement) if you need special formatting or display

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge it doesnt work in IE unless you style the `select` tag:

```
select{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

However this will influence all options. I dont know of another css-only solution, but would be interested in one as-well :)

Answer (score -1):

Just try,

css

```
option:first-child {
     font-weight:bold;   
   }
```

HTMl

```
<select id="htmldisabled">
    <option>test1</option>
    <option>test2</option>
    <option>test3</option>
    <option>test4</option>
    <option>test5</option>
    <option>test6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This doesn't work is IE either. Please test answers before post unless your certain they work.

Comment: @anglimass please look at OP. I need to bold the first option of the select box, not applying color.