# Dropdown List styles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to bold the first option of a select across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356797/how-to-bold-the-first-option-of-a-select-across-all-browsers)

How do we need to code for a drop down list so that only first item among the dropdownlist is in italics and in different color.

Answer (score 3):

Css does the trick...

```
select option:first-child{
 font-style:italic;
 color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/79dk5/