# IOS Safari <select> element

Tags: html, css, ios, mobile-safari

I have a hierarchal dropdown menu that visually differentiates hierarchy by using space characters

**Example**

```
<select>
    <option value='1'>Top Level Item</option>
    <option value='2'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lower Level Item</option>
    <option value='3'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Another Lower Level Item</option>
    <option value='4'>Another Top Level Item</option>
</select>
```

This works well in all browsers except for the iPhone where the spaces are ignored and all items are shown at the same level.

I'm using a reactive design (same DOM for mobile and desktop) and have decided that integrating jQuery Mobile just for the themed select isn't a good option.

Are there any easy work arounds or small plugins that might help me accomplish this for IOS browsers?

`<optgroup>` elements are not a good fit b/c some of the parent options can be selected. `<optgroup>` do not allow for selecting the parent categories as best as I can tell

The core of the requirement for this feature is that all of a particular site's navigation must be on one dropdown like element that is touch friendly.

Comment: Use dashes instead of spaces.

Comment: Dashes will work but doubtfully will meet our style guidelines. Thanks though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might try to start your hierarchy-divider with the Zero Width Joiner / Zero Width Non-Joiner Entity using: `&zwj;` or `&zwnj;`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it achieves the intended result. Just add an `&zwj;` before your `&nbsp;`s.

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative is to use an HTML/CSS replacement for `<SELECT>`.

See: [jQuery select box replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021836/jquery-select-box-replacement)

Comment: you're right, there is no way to do it with a vanilla `<select>`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well for my needs, but it's not completely perfect -- on desktop there's an unselectable line at the top.

```
<select>
    <optgroup>
        <option value='1'>Top Level Item</option>
        <option value='2'>&zwj;&nbsp;&zwj;&nbsp;&zwj;&nbsp;Lower Level Item</option>
        <option value='3'>&zwj;&nbsp;&zwj;&nbsp;&zwj;&nbsp;Another Lower Level Item</option>
        <option value='4'>Another Top Level Item</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: That "empty" Line is supposed to be there whenever you use the optgroup node. You failed to add its Label Attribute... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup